# I can't shift to the largest chainring

Tags: road-bike, shifter

Please help. The derailleur seems to be fine, I'm suspecting the handle. I can't shift to the largest chainring at the front, it drops back to the second largest ring as soon as I release the shifter. I need to keep the pressure on the shifter in order for the derailleur to maintain its position on the largest ring, or else it will drop back to the second one.

Comment: Welcome to the bikes SE site! By “handle”, do you mean you suspect the shifter is not working?

Comment: It could be that the cable is just slightly loose, or it could be that the high limit screw on the derailer is screwed in about a turn too far.  A vague possibility that the shifter itself is defective, but probably not.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s quickly review how your bike shifts. Your front derailleur rests in the small ring position. When you move your left shifter to the big ring position, you pull cable, and that pulls your FD to the outside position. The same principle applies to the rear derailleur, which rests on the smallest cog, and gets pulled to the big cog. There's a ratchet inside each shifter that controls the amount of cable it pulls per shift.

The thing with cables is that they stretch over time. So, there may be a bit of slack in the cable, and your shifter isn't pulling as much cable as it should. This means your front derailleur doesn't move as far outward as it should. This happens with new bikes - I distinctly remember this happening on my first bike, and I was having trouble shifting both front and rear. The same issue will probably happen to your rear derailleur.

If this is a new bike, chances are the bike store asked you to come in after a few weeks for a free tune up - they’d adjust your cables. You can take them up on it. Alternatively, you can adjust your bike yourself. It likely seems complex at first, but the mechanisms are fairly simple once you understand them. Park Tools has a nice [post](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-adjustment) explaining how to do this, and the post also has an embedded YouTube video. If it’s just cable stretch, you will only need to twist the cable barrel adjuster, and you can skip the bits about setting the limit screws.

Basically, righty tighty (I.e. turn clockwise to tighten) on almost all bolts on the bike. When you turn the cable adjuster clockwise, you push the barrel further in, which slackens the cable. Turn it anti-clockwise instead to tighten the cable.

If you have gone and adjusted your limit screws, you’ll need to re-adjust them carefully. The symptoms you describe can be explained by new bike and cable stretch, so I will not describe the limit screws right now.

(A previous version of this answer wrongly described what to do for just the rear derailleur. The title of the post initially said "cog", which is standard terminology for the gears in the back. We would say "chainring" to mean the rings on the crank, i.e. the front. The principle is the same, it's just that cable stretch affects each derailleur in a different direction.)

Comment: Thanks for helping, but the problem is not on the rear gears, it's on the front. When shifting it outwards to the largest cogs from the second, there is no usual "tick" feeling and it won't stay on the largest cogs if I release the shifter.

Comment: @TheKingsman I should have read your post more closely, but in normal usage, “cog” means sprocket at the rear. We would say “chainring” if we meant one of the front chainrings.

Answer (score 1):

From the original description and comments it sounds like the shifter cable is too loose thus the shifter cannot move the front derailleur far enough to get the second "click".

The first thing to do is check if this is the case and how much extra slack is in the cable.

To check this, pedal the bike shift the front derailleur all the way to the smallest chainring. It's ok to shift it a couple extra clicks just to make sure the front shifter has released all the cable.  Some front derailleur have intermediate points (half clicks).

You can also gently pull on the cable with one finger while shifting up/down to feel the tension increases/decrease with each shift. Since this is a triple crankset, there should be at least two clicks. So count how many clicks you feel going up and down.

With the chain on the small ring, check to see if there is any tension in the cable. It should have just enough tension such that when the shift lever is moved the derailleur will also move.  If the shift lever moves but the derailleur doesn't move then the cable has too loose and this is a problem.

To remove the extra slack, you'll need to loosen the cable fixing bolt on the derailleur. pull the cable taught and then cinch down the fixing bolt.

If the cable is too tight the front derailleur will not be able to go all the way to the left. This isn't common but it's possible to do. When you test the front shifting, if the chain rubs the left side of the front derailleur when the chain is also in the largest cog in back, then the cable is either too tight OR the low limit screw needs to be adjusted out (turned counterclockwise).

Another way to increase tension on the front derailleur cable is via the cable adjusting barrel. For a road bike where the brake lever (handle?) also doubles for the shift lever, the cable adjusting barrel usually is on the frame.  Unscrewing (turning counterclockwise) the barrel will increase the tension of the cable and should help with the shifting. Not all bikes have adjusting barrels for the front derailleur. Bikes with flat handlebars (mountain, commuter, comfort) will have the adjusting barrel on the shifter unit and not the frame.

If the cable does not need adjustment, then the problem might be the high (large ring) limit adjusting screw. If the screw is too far in will prevent the derailleur from moving far enough to the right for the chain to get up and onto the large ring. From the original discussion and comments this doesn't seem to be the case as you said you could keep the chain in the large ring if you kept pressure on the handle.

One more possibility is if the cable is much too tight so the derailleur never reaches the "full release" click for the low gear (small chainring). In this case the one remaining click gets the chain to the middle chainring. But additional shifts up do not result in a click so the chain falls back from the large to the middle chainring.

To check for and fix this problem, again shift to the small chainring. Loosen the cable fixing bolt until the cable can slide. If there is too much tension the cable will move a good 1/4 inch or so.  Using pliers pull on the cable to get a little tension and tighten down the fixing bolt.

Just an FYI for clarity:
Gears in front connected to the cranks & pedals are typically referred to as "chainrings".
The individual gears in the back are referred to as cogs and are part of a freewheel or cassette.

Hope this helps,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

Others have said that the cable is slightly too long which prevents the shifter pulling the derailleur cage over far enough to keep the chain on the largest chainring. This is possible but I suspect that the shifter itself may have a problem and is not staying in the large chainring position.

> I need to keep the pressure on the shifter in order for the derailleur to maintain its position on the largest ring, or else it will drop back to the second one.

When you shift to the largest chainring then release the shifter is the derailleur cage moving back to the second position taking the chain with it? If this is the case the shifter is possibly broken, or gummed up with dried grease which can prevent the rachet mechanism from engaging. Others write that flushing with WD40 or another solvent can cure this. Otherwise you'll need to replace the shifter.

If the chain falls to the second chainring but the derailleur does not move back, then cable adjustment is very likely the issue.

Derailleur adjustment is tricky and hard to describe properly so I like to refer people to these Park Tool pages that include videos that visually explain the adjustment process and how the derailleurs work.

https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustment

https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-adjustment

Answer (score 0):

The shift lever may be loose.

On a bike with a friction thumb shifter there is a screw or a "D" ring screw that can be tightened so the lever won't pull back once released.
[image: Thumb shifter]

On a bike with shift levers there may be a screw, "D" ring screw, or a wingnut that can be tightened.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

An additional cause can be a partially-frayed inner cable.  This is known to happen inside the mechanism of many types of brifter (integrated road bike shifter).

Curiously, pod shifters/trigger shifters have a much smoother path and don't tend to stress the cable as much.  This is partially because a brifter combines brakes and shifters, and every braking action also flexes the gear cable head.

Over time the gear cable kinks, and can break strands, until at worst it will separate completely.   As the strands break, the cable's effective length increases, which can cause that "not quite far enough" effect you're seeing.

Upshot **Check your inner cables** and replace as required.

Best practice is to replace all inner cables every 10,000 km or bi-annually, whichever is first.  Also do it a month before any big race/ride events so the new ones have a chance to settle in.

If the cable does break off, getting the head out can be difficult.  Its even hard to pull the cable if a strand has snagged on something.

[image]

[image] 
 this is a motorbike clutch cable, but the effect is similar.